# pthreads v3 / PHP 7 / PDOException: You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances

Tags: php, multithreading, serialization, pdo, pthreads

I'm using the pthreads v3 extension for PHP 7 and I have a **WORKER class** as well as a **JOB class**.

The code, that I use below should work in older versions, since I saw many people using it. But now it does not anymore.

My goal is to use a PDO database connection in the **JOB class**. I tried so many things and nothing seems to work except using the MySQLi-extension, but I don't want to use it.

So my question is: What do I have to do to create a PDO connection for every **JOB class** without the fatal error I mentioned above?

I saw this code multiple times online as a solution for the error:

*"Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances in ..."*.

```
class MyWorker extends Worker{


    public static $pdo;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->hostname = DBHOST;
        $this->username = DBUSER;
        $this->password = DBPASS;
        $this->database = DBNAME;
    }


    public function run() {

            self::$pdo = new PDO(
                "mysql:host=".$this->hostname.";port=3306;dbname=".$this->database, $this->username, $this->password);
    }



    public function getConnection() {

        return self::$pdo;

    }


}








class Job extends Threaded
{


    public function run()
    {

        $this->db = $this->worker->getConnection();  // HERE IS THE ERROR!

        // code, that connects to database ...


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some hours trying kind of everything, I found the mistake.

The mistake was, that I called **$this->db** even though this attribute did not even exist in the class:

```
$this->db = $this->worker->getConnection();
```

Instead you just have to declare a new variable, for example **$db**:

```
$db = $this->worker->getConnection();
```

Maybe someone loses some hours searching for this little mistake as well and I could help with this post :)